# using remote control after pauseMissionWithCompletion in DJI SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

After pausing a mission using pauseMissionWithCompletion, i'm trying to manually move the aircraft to a different position using the remote control but the joystick does not respond to my inputs. However, if I resume the mission, the aircraft's flight can be overridden by the joystick. Does anyone know how to enable the joystick while the mission is paused?

Answer (score 0):

Some missions might make the aircraft enter `virtualStickMode` (all missions which include yaw movement do that). If you pause the mission when it is in `virtualStickMode`, you will not have control of the joysticks. If you really want joystick control after pausing mission, you can flip the mode on the remote to atti mode and back, that should give you back the control of joysticks. However, I think it also does cancel the mission.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish what you want - pause the mission, move to a different location, and then resume the mission. If you want accomplish what you are looking for is to: stop the mission. Set move via joystick and/or virtual stick to a different location. Then upload the remainder of the mission.